# Select rows where jsonb array contains any string in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, jsonb

This is my SQL so far:

```
select * from table where table.json_info @> '{"search_tags":["hello", "world"]}'
```

And this works if the row has BOTH `hello` and `world` in the `search_tags`

I'm wondering if there is a way to include rows that have EITHER `hello` OR `world` and of course those that have both.

Thanks to all ahead of time!

Comment: select * from table where table.json_info @> '{"search_tags":["hello"]}' or '{"search_tags":[ "world"]}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @utility for putting me on the right track here.

This is what I wound up with:

```
select * from table where table.json_info @> '{"search_tags":["hello"]}' or table.json_info @> '{"search_tags":[ "world"]}'
```